# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Please help me figure it out. The code worked until last Friday with no problems.
Today after several launches I am consistently getting the error:

google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))

And I can neither download nor send data to Big Query.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    load_dotenv('.env')
    
    
    def create_bq_conn():
        CREDS_BIG_QUERY = r'C:\Users\path_to_file\some_creds.json'
        bclient = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(json_credentials_path=CREDS_BIG_QUERY)
        return bclient
    
    def result_df():
        query_job = create_bq_conn().query('SELECT * FROM `table`') 
        bqdf = query_job.to_dataframe()
        return bqdf
    
    result_df()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many workarounds in solving this SSL error is by using `pip install certifi` or `pip install --upgrade certifi` if you already installed it.

You can use this syntax to determine the path of your certificate:

```
import certifi
certifi.where()
```

The path file will be generated:

```
'/user/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'
```

Now, you can pass the path to verify:

```
r = requests.get('url', verify='/user/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem')
```